# How to follow an object in a window in python using pyglet

Tags: python, window, pyglet

Im creating a simulator of a car driving on a lane, im using pyglet and im trying to make the window follow a car ive made.
i tried to use - `window.set_location` but it moves the ectual window.
im just trying to make it follow my car's chassis, **i have the car's chassis position** but i dont know what to do with it.

thanks for the helpers.

Comment: you have to change positions (x,y) for all objects which you draw in window. If car should move `N`-pixel left then don't move it but move all other objects `N`-pixel right. This way car is always in the same place on window and other object moves. You can also create variable `offset_X, offset_Y` for tor this. When car moves N-pixel left then change it `(x,y)` and add/substract this value from `offset_X` - and later use this value to all objects when you draw them (but don't add it to all `(x,y)` permanently)

Comment: Is it not possible to make the window focus on a spesific object?

Comment: `window` is used only to display window on desktop and it doesn't care what you display inside window. You have to decide what to display and in which place inside window. You have to use offset to move all objects inside window and keep car in the center. In some gema's tutorials this offset is called `camera` (or `scrolling camer`)